# Logic behind "at most"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does the term 'at most' mean there is at least one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No because

> "at most one"

means

> one or less.

**Edit**
The [free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/at+most) points out that *at most* can be replaced by "not more than".

In which case

- *at most one* can be equated to **not more than one**,

whereas instead

- *at least one* means **not less than one**.

Comment: Alain, thank you very much.  Do you have a resource for this, I tried searching everywhere online, didn't have any success.

Comment: @KexPhilo, I've edited the answer to start from a dictionary definition, if this is what you are after.

Answer (score -1):

It means "no more than one."  Many times it is used to imply "no more than one, if even that."